# unable to mount my external hard disk in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount

I am using ubuntu 14.04, My external hard disk is not mounting here.
it gives error that :

[image]

My Ex. hard disk were mount easily.I don't no what happen.
I have tried this

```
vikky@vikky-Inspiron-5558:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc
[sudo] password for vikky: 
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
vikky@vikky-Inspiron-5558:~$
```

When I see the the information of drive in GParted :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not very good at repairing NTFS.

In order to reduce the chance of lost data, I suggest you run check disk from a Windows box.

Don't know how to do that? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/

Answer (score 0):

try testdisk
here is a link to a forum thread of someone with a simmilar problem who used testdisk to fix a PBR problem
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2129262